# Error in selector with a percent character in a LESS file

Tags: css, less, gruntjs, recess

I have a div with an ID which contains a percentage symbol, like this:

```
<div id="foo%bar">
    stuff
</div>
```

And I cant avoid that, is a div that I cant change so I need to deal with that :(

I am trying to reach that element using LESS but I get an error in the line that contains the percentage when I try to compile the LESS file:

[image: error]

To compile the LESS file I'm using recess (https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-recess), a GruntJS plugin. If someone know any other tool to compile LESS files avoiding this error I will be happy to change to use it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While that is a valid (HTML5) id, it is not a valid CSS selector. From the [Selectors Level 3 docs (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

You can use a backslash character to escape the percent sign in the selector and make it valid:

```css
#foo\%bar {
    color:red
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gd2FT/5/)

Comment: Helped me compile a style against the jQuery.select2 generated class .select2-selection--multiple (I escaped as ".select2-selection\--multiple")

Answer (score 1):

It's not a valid selector; if you have a look at JSFiddle this will not be styled. Instead, use an attribute selector, that way you'll get the expected result and your LESS will be compiled.

```
[id*="bar"][id*="baz"] {
    color:red
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gd2FT/2/

The best option is to refactor and remove the percentages, but I think this will suffice in the short term.

Edit: Alternatively, simpler is better:

```
[id="bar%baz"] {
    color:red
}
```